# nginx specify server for a particular request

Tags: nginx, upload, load-balancing, distributed, sticky-session

Let's say I have `ip_hash;` turned on for load balancing between 4 different servers. So, client's IP address is used as a hashing key to determine which server his requests get routed to.

However, for **file upload**, it's best to keep **all files in a single server**. So, I want all `/upload` requests get routed to server 1 **for any client**. This means all requests obey IP-hash, except `POST /upload` which must be sent to server 1.

Is there a way to create this exception in NGINX? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define two `upstream` containers, one with full load balancing and another with the POST specific service requirements:

```
upstream balancing { ... }
upstream uploading { ... }
```

Also, within the `http` container, define a `map` of the request method:

```
map $request_method $upstream {
    default balancing;
    POST    uploading;
}
```

Finally, within the `server` container, define a specific `proxy_pass` for the `/upload` URI:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://balancing;
}
location /upload {
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
}
```

The upstream specification is evaluated from the value of the `REQUEST_METHOD`.